# Может и - нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужно ли дробить запятой **может и** и ставить запятую после "может"?

1. Тебе что, жить надоело? А **может(,) и** надоело.
2. В ящике валялся молоток, а **может(,) и** еще что-то.
3. Хотя у себя в сарае химикатов я не видел, **может(,) и** у соседей их не будет.
4. Сходи в "Пятёрочку", узнай, что там за работа, **может(,) и** трудоустроишься.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Запятая ставится:

*Тебе что, жить надоело? **А может**, и надоело. В ящике валялся молоток, **а может**, и еще что-то. Хотя у себя в сарае химикатов я не видел, **может**, и у соседей их не будет. Сходи в "Пятёрочку", узнай, что там за работа, **может**, и трудоустроишься.*

**Пояснение**

Союз ***И*** в данном случае является **усилительной** частицей и относится к следующему после вводного сочетания **слову**: *и  надоело, и еще, и у соседей, и трудоустроишься*.

**Вопрос № 209760**

Будьте добры, подскажите, правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в таком предложении: "Может, да, а, может, и нет". Спасибо. ОТВЕТ. **Правильно:** *Может, да, **а может**, и нет.*

**[Словарь Ефремовой](https://gufo.me/dict/efremova/%D0%B8):**

**И, II част.** Употребляется при подчеркивании или **при усилении смысла** отдельного слова или целого высказывания, соответствуя по значению сл.: также, **даже**, уж, хотя.